# Sub-$1000 iSCSI NAS options

Tags: iscsi, network-attached-storage

I'm in the market for a sub-$1000 NAS solution for a small development/QA network. Needs to be reliable and something we won't worry about overnight, but does not need to be bulletproof/5 nines/what have you.

A few avenues we have explored are:

- the Sans Digital AccuNAS series, such
  as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003SE6R0W).
- [OpenFiler](http://openfiler.com) plus a spare PC

Anyone have any experience with those solutions or other recommendations in this space?

Clarifications

- We are going to principally be
  hosting Hyper-V virtual machines to
  it.
- 500gb should be more than enough disk
  space
- Performance isn't a main concern, but
  it should be fast enough as to not
  cause the DEV/QA applications issues.
- Looking at mainly iSCSI -- we are
  effectively replacing a 8xSAS drive
  internal array with this.  NAS could
  come in handy in a pinch

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? VMware or other virtualization? Simple file storage? How much disk space do you need? How many users will need to simultaneously access it? Are you concerned about performance? It might help to [look over these charts](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/nas/nas-charts) if you are.  Do you need NAS + iSCSI or just iSCSI?

Comment: iSCSI is a SAN technology, not NAS.

Comment: a lot of the new nas servers support exposing volumes via iscsi along with nas volumes.

Comment: Currently you shouldn't use nas to host your vhds, it can be done but is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openfiler works perfectly fine as ISCSI target with virtualized enviroments (VMware or Citrix Xen). 
However you will require good hardware to meet your expectations.

Comment: Agreed. OpenFiler saved mi life in an installation where the supplier provided Win 2003 R2 for Storage as a SAN OS. Windows turned out useless and full of bugs. I wiped windows, installed OpenFiler and averything worked as advertised.

Answer (score 4):

OpenFiler is pretty good for most people, if you can afford to then try to put it in a server with dual power-supplies, dual-NICs setup for failover and use RAID 1 or 10 - that would be pretty stable without going too far.